# Understanding Fixed time step

Tags: physics

From what I understand about time based Euler Integration is that you will set a number of pixels you want your object to move in the space of second and then the value will be regulated based on the frame-rate of the machine your running the game on.

What I'm having issue with is this

```
 You will set your acceleration

 acceleration = 30;
```

Then that acceleration will be added to the velocity and multiplied by the time 
   which would be say  0.0166667 if the frame-rate is 60fps which will cut down the
   velocity to the appropriate number for that frame which would be 0.50001

```
velocity += acceleration * dt;
```

but then when you add the velocity to the position it yet again multiplies the result by 0.0166667 which leaves you with 0.0833366667

```
position += velocity * dt;
```

What I'm trying to get is that instead of the 30 pixels per second I initially intended for the character to move I will need to put in an acceleration value of 1800.

I was wondering why this is done instead of simply multiplying the acceleration by the dt and leaving it at that ?

Comment: If you have a `dt` variable then it is not a fixed timestep. Fixed timestep is when the game logic is guaranteed to run a certain number of times per second, so you don't have to worry about `dt` (i.e. `dt` is constant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acceleration is in units per second per second; it is the change in velocity over time. So you have to multiply it by time to get the change in velocity (units per second).

Similarly, velocity is in units per second; it is the change in position over time. So you have to multiply it by time to get the change in position (units).

You are not multiplying something by `dt` twice; you are multiplying the acceleration by `dt` to get the velocity change and adding it to velocity, then multiplying the velocity by `dt` to get the position change and adding it to position.

Comment: Correct. This usually works like `something.x += (something.velocity * fractionalSecondsSinceLastUpdate)`.

Answer (score 0):

First you should understand that fixed time step is really much simpler than variable time step. If you like you can throw away `dt` completely, then your numbers will simply be per time step rather than per second.

Actually the only reason for including a `dt` in your code is that it makes it easy to change the update frequency while keeping everything else mostly constant.